# Como Fazer a seguinte função em javascript puro?

Tags: javascript, html5, django, django-templates

Eu gostaria de fazer o seguinte cálculo:
pegar o valor de valor a pagar,pegar o valor dos dias de atraso e que ao clicar no botão confirmar faça o seguinte calculo: valor_a_pagar*(atraso*2)/100, tentei isso mas não deu certo

html:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label> Pagamento De Janeiro</label>
  <br>
  {% for s in students %}
  <span>Valor a pagar <strong id="pag_jan">{{s.fee}}</strong><div class="form-content"><form>
      <div class="input-group mb-3"> <label>Dias de atraso</label><input type="search" placeholder="" 
           name="atraso" id="atraso" value="0">
        <button class="btn btn-light" type="submit" onclick="calc()">confirmar</button></span>
  {%endfor%}
  {% render_field form.jan_pay class="form-control" %}
  
</div>

<script>
   var pag= document.getElementById("pag_jan")
   var result= pag.innerText
   var atraso = document.getElementById("atraso")
   var result_atraso = atraso.value

   function calc(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
        if(result_atraso <=0 ){
          return
     }else{
      var resultado =  result*(result_atraso*2)/100
      console.log(resultado)
    }
   }

     
</script>
```

Comment: mas esse código já é js puro

Comment: mas ele não funciona

Comment: então precisa fazer debug e descobrir o que acontece, olhar no console e ver se tem erros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está pegando o valor `atraso.value` fora da função `calc`. Então esse valor é carregado apenas uma vez, quando a página é carregada, e nunca mais é atualizado.

Se a ideia é pegar o que foi preenchido, pegue o valor dentro da função:

```js
// os elementos podem ser pegos fora da função mesmo
var pag = document.getElementById("pag_jan");
var atraso = document.getElementById("atraso");

function calc(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // pegue os valores dentro da função
  var result = pag.innerText;
  var result_atraso = atraso.value;

  if (result_atraso <= 0) {
    return;
  } else {
    var resultado =  result * (result_atraso * 2) / 100;
    console.log(resultado);
  }
}

// associar o evento de clique à função calc
document.getElementById("botao").addEventListener('click', calc);
```

```html
<label> Pagamento De Janeiro</label>
<br>
<span>Valor a pagar <strong id="pag_jan">100</strong>
  <form>
    <label>Dias de atraso</label>
    <input type="search" name="atraso" id="atraso" value="0">
    <button id="botao">confirmar</button>
  </form>
</span>
```

E no JavaScript também coloquei ponto-e-vírgula no final das linhas. Pode parecer "frescura", e sei que o JavaScript "aceita" o código sem ponto e vírgula e "funciona", mas isso evita algumas situações bizarras que podem ocorrer se você não usá-los, como [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169596) e [essa](/q/432960/112052) (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](/q/3341/112052)).

Comment: Obrigado amigo funcionou, eu já tinha ouvido falar sobre os ponto e virgulas mas como eu programo muito em python acabo esquecendo